# How to send data from IntentService to Non-Activity class

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, intentservice

I have two Service class. one is `WebsocketService(extends Service)` to manage `Websocket related function` and `SocketMessageProcessing(extends IntentService)` to `process response Received in WebSocketService`. From `Non-Activity(SocketImpl)` class I am successfully able to send data to `WebsocketService`. But I am having trouble in sending response back to `SocketImpl` class from `SocketMessageProcessing` class.

```
//Common Class To send data to WebsocketService and Receive response from SocketMessageProcessing Service When Work Done. I am using this class as callback.
public class SocketImpl{

    private String json;
    private Context mContext;
    private WebServiceResponseListener mListener;

    public SocketImpl(Context context, String json, WebServiceResponseListener mListener){
    //Initilize variables
    }

    public void execute() {
        //Send request to websocket 
        WebSocketService.sendMessage(mAdapter.getContxet(), json);
    }

    public void onResponse(String resp, String tag) {
    //Here I would like to receive response from IntenService Class.
    }

}
```

```
//This class will perform Websocket related function and it will send response to SocketMessageProcessing once response received.
public class WebSocketService extends Service {
      ...

      private void processResponse(String message){
              Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SocketMessageProcessing.class);
              intent.putExtra("DATA", message);
              mContext.startService(intent);
      }
}


//Intent service to Process the incoming websocket response, And Send response Back to Class Where Its originate(SocketImpl).
public class SocketMessageProcessing extends IntentService{

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String json = intent.getStringExtra("DATA");
        //Process json and send data back to class from where request originate?
    }

}
```

Below things I have tried so far.

1. `LocalBroadcastManager`
   As I want to receive response in Non-Activity class I don’t know how to  manage the `register` and `unregister` the `BroadcastReceiver`.
2. Cache `SocketImpl` Object and get that Object in `SocketMessageProcessing` and tried calling `onResponse()`. But I did get `"sending message to a handler on a dead thread"` exception, So think it is not a good idea. because onResponse method perform many UI related operations.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1 that you suggested is the standard way. And you just need a context object to be able to register and unregister

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(...
```

I've just tried that in my app from a non-Activity class (using an activity context which it needs anyway) and it works fine. I'm not sure what you mean by

> I don’t know how to manage the register and unregister the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: thanks for your replay. I really appreciate our answer. Actually If it is a Activity class then Broadcast Receiver Works fine for me. But in Non-Activity class(Activity class>>Fragment class>>Adapter class>>Listener class, Here Listener class is Non-Activity class) i don't have access to onResume or onPause method. so i don't  know how to register and unregister broadcast receiver there.

Comment: because what i understood is we need to register broadcast receiver in onResume method and unregister in onPause method.

Comment: So your question is *when* to register and unregister? I guess it depends on your situation but you can register in the constructor for example and unregister in a special method that you keep for cleaning up resource and is called when that object is not longer needed by your application.

Comment: Registration doesn't need to happen in onResume. See the LocalBroadcastManager documentation. "Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process" it doesn't mention anything about having to be used within an Activity, but instead "local objects within your process"

Comment: Okay lets say i have class called ItemDeleteListener which implements onClickListener. So on ItemDeleteListener constructor i will register the Broadcast Receiver, So when does i unregister again.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your use case?

Comment: just give me a moment.

Comment: @Nanos Is it okay if we doesn't unregister the receiver.

Comment: You can unregister as soon as you don't need to receive broadcasts anymore. I don't know the details of your app (outside of the Adapter code scope that you mentioned) to give any insights but I think there should be multiple ways to do so.

Comment: @DhavalPatel it's recommended to always unregister the receiver when you don't need it to save system resources. Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Nanos Your answer did help me a lot to solve my problem. Thanks.:-)